# Persistent shared memory in windows

Tags: winapi, shared-memory

I want a named shared memory region that survives process termination. Memory region and data should be accessible even if no program has an open handle temporarily. Only a reboot should "release" the shared resource. How can I do this?

My current solution: a keep-alive-process with an open handle.

Comment: What about a file?

Comment: I choose shared memory for the read/write/sync speed. A file is not deleted on reboot.

Comment: if you have (or can got) `SE_CREATE_PERMANENT_PRIVILEGE` and use `ZwCreateSection` you can set `OBJ_PERMANENT` in attributes. as result your section object (file mapping on win32 language) will be permanent until system reboot or somebody call `ZwMakeTemporaryObject`.  `SE_CREATE_PERMANENT_PRIVILEGE` usually have only *LocalSystem* but if you 'Admin` (more exactly you have `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE` - possible get and `SE_CREATE_PERMANENT_PRIVILEGE`)

Comment: Files can be deleted on reboot, and files can be mapped into memory.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - can of course, but need add some code, which do this (delete files). formally exact solution is us Zw api [An object is permanent if it was created with the OBJ_PERMANENT object attribute specified.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566477(v=vs.85).aspx)  here most difficult (relative i be say) got needed privilege. but of curse undocumented, unusual etc..

Comment: @RbMm the only code you need to delete a file on reboot is to call `MoveFileEx()` with the `MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT` flag and `lpNewFileName` set to NULL.

Comment: Sounds like persisting a memory-mapped files until reboot.

Answer (score 0):

`NtMakePermanentObject(HANDLE)` sets the `OBJ_PERMANENT` attribute on an already-created named object, making it not go away when all handles disappear. That function was added in XP. In all versions of NT, you can also specify `OBJ_PERMANENT` when creating an object if you use the NT native API to create it.

Unfortunately, both methods of setting `OBJ_PERMANENT` will fail if you don't have `SeCreatePermanentPrivilege` (`SE_CREATE_PERMANENT_NAME`), which most accounts generally don't, even administrators. Workarounds include:

- Add the privilege to the account.
- If you can create services, have a service running as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, which normally does have the privilege, do it.

  - [`PsExec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) `-s some.exe` will run any executable as SYSTEM; it creates a service to do it under the hood.
- If you have `SeDebugPrivilege` (`SE_DEBUG_NAME`), which lets you bypass all security checks in `OpenProcess`, you can forget about `OBJ_PERMANENT` and just dup a handle to your object into `smss.exe` or `winlogon.exe` or something. I'm mentioning this because it seems to be much more common for administrators to have `SeDebugPrivilege` than `SeCreatePermanentPrivilege`, as ridiculous as that sounds.

`NtMakeTemporaryObject(HANDLE)`, which clears `OBJ_PERMANENT`, exists in all versions of NT. It only requires a handle with delete access, no special privileges.